# Java8 generate a map, it has key from each item in a list and it has value from a pair for that list

Tags: java-8

```
public enum MyEnum {

    A(1, Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 100, 101)),

    B(2, Arrays.asList(4))
    
    private Integer code,
    private List<Integer> types;
    
    MyEnum(Integer code, List<Integer> types) {
        this.code = code;
        this.types = types;
    }
}
```

I want to generate a `Map<Integer, Integer> map` based on the above enum, which has key from each element in `types` and value from that `types`'s `code`.

```
This is map (k,v) from A:

(0, 1)
(1, 1)
(2, 1)
(3, 1)
(100, 1)
(101, 1)
This is from B:
(4,2)
```

This is what I am currently stuck at:

```
Arrays.stream(MyEnum.values()).collect(Collectors.toMap(???, MyEnum::getCode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` for this purpose

```java
Map<Integer, Integer> result = Arrays.stream(MyEnum.values())
                .flatMap(myEnum -> myEnum.getTypes().stream().map(type -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(type, myEnum.getCode())))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative that uses [mapMulti](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)).  But first, a couple observations.

You need to include two getters to retrieve the `types` and the `code`.  The `code` getter is basic, but the `types` getter needs consideration.

- when returning a modifiable list or array it is best to make a defensive copy or render the returned copy unmodifiable<sup>*</sup>
- The easiest way is to return `List.copyOf(types)` which returns an unmodifiable list.
- An alternative is to return `new ArrayList<>(types)` which returns a new modifiable list that doesn't affect the original if modified.
- and lastly you could just assign an unmodifable copy during construction of `MyEnum`, then you can return the types list normally.
- The above recommendations depend entirely on your use case.

Now for the solution.

- mapMulti allows one to put selective items on the stream as required.  It can eliminate the need for a `flatMap` which can incur some additional overhead.
- here, the body of `mapMulti` iterates over the types and packages the type and codes in an entry. Then that entry is placed on the stream via `accept`.  [Map.entryof](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#entry(K,V)) is simply a method that returns an unmodifiable entry of the proper types.
- Then the entry is simply put into a map using its key/value.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> result = Arrays.stream(MyEnum.values())
        .<Entry<Integer, Integer>>mapMulti((type, consumer) -> {
            for (int typ : type.getTypes()) {
                consumer.accept(Map.entry(typ, type.getCode()));
            }
        }).collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));

result.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
0=1
1=1
2=1
3=1
100=1
4=2
101=1
```

The keys are in no particular order since maps are unordered based on their `hashCode`. If you want them to be stored in their encounter order (as shown in your question), you can use a [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

```
Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (a,b)->a, LinkedHashMap::new)
```

The merge function `(a,b)->a` is not needed here but syntactically required.

---

<sup>*</sup>If the objects in lists or arrays contain objects that can be modifiable then those objects may need similar handling.

Answer (score 0):

**BE SIMPLE!!!**

```java
public static Map<Integer, Integer> convert() {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (MyEnum myEnum : MyEnum.values())
        for (int type : myEnum.getTypes())
            map.put(type, myEnum.getCode());

    return map;
}
```

---

```java
public static Map<Integer, Integer> convert() {
    return Arrays.stream(MyEnum.values())
                 .flatMap(myEnum -> myEnum.getTypes().stream()
                                        .map(type -> Map.entry(type, myEnum.getCode())))
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}
```

From my point of view, the **1st** snippet is much more better. It's easier, simplier and never make you hesitating while reading after a while of coding it.